# MS Access form with value inserted automatically

Tags: ms-access-2010

On a MS Access form with 2 entries to fill, from values present 2 tables, I want to to the floowing:
The first 2 entries have values retrieved from combo boxes, and I want that in the 3rd one, the value is inserted automatically using info from the previous ones, maybe pressing a button associated with a macro (or other way)

```
TABLE CITIES   
-----------------------------
Town        |   Abbreviation   
------------+---------------- 
New York    |   NY    
Los Angeles |   LA


TABLE COUNTRIES    
-----------------------------   
Country |   Abbreviation   
--------+--------------------   
France  |      FR
Italy   |      IT
```

Example:

1st Entry -->   Town:  New York

2nd Entry -->   Country: Italy

3rd Entry -->  NY-IT

How can this be accomplished? How can I put a button associated with a query,instead of a combo box (In the case that's the best way to do this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just expanding on what @Fionnuala has mentioned. I would put it inside a validation as you do not want values like `NY-` or `-IT`, so only if both combo boxes are filled the code will have `NY-IT`

```
Private Sub firstCombo_AfterUpdate()
    updateCombo
End If

Private Sub secondCombo_AfterUpdate()
    updateCombo
End If

Private Sub updateCombo()
    If Me.firstcombo.ListIndex = -1 Or Me.secondCombo.ListIndex = -1 Then
        Me.thirdcombo = vbNullString
    Else
        Me.thirdCombo = Me.firstcombo.Column(2) & "-" & Me.secondCombo.Column(2)
    End If
End sub
```

I am pretty sure New York is not in Italy, so maybe a proper validation might be in order. Also why does the third need to be a ComboBox? Could it not be a simple TextBox?

Apart from this, you might want to look into [Cascading CombobBoxes](http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut10.htm), where it would be a lot more smooth to handle this sort of scenarios.

Comment: Sorry for my bad choice of example. Both answers were helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use the column property of the comboboxes. For example:

1st Combo

```
 SELECT Id, Town, Abbreviation
```

2nd Combo

```
 SELECT Id, Country, Abbreviation
```

You will now need an AfterUpdate event for each combo, say

```
 Me.3rdText = Me.1stCombo.Column(2) & "-" & Me.2ndCombo.Column(2)
```

Columns count from zero, however, the ColumnCount property would be 3 in both cases (that is 0,1,2=3). You must make sure to have the correct column counts and column widths.